# Compiler asm bytecode expression

Tags: java, assembly, compiler-construction, jvm, bytecode

How can I calculate the expression `2==2` in asm bytecode without using the new `JumpInsNode(Opcodes.IF_ICMPEQ)`?

Also I want to store the result in a variable.  e.x print (2==2) the result must be 1

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could push both operands onto the stack and apply an `ixor` instruction; if the result is zero, the operands are equal.

```
bipush 2
bipush 2
ixor   // stack holds 0 if operands are equal, nonzero if not equal
```

Any particular reason you don't want to use a branch instruction?

Comment: Yes check this out. I want to do this write 2==2; and the result will be 0 or 1.Branch instruction will not be useful or maybe it is i don't know. What you suggest?

Comment: Does the result have to be 0 or 1?  What is wrong with 0 or non-zero?

Comment: No  0 or non-zero is fine . One more question if i have 2<=2 or 2>2 etc what instruction do i use to get the same result?

Comment: Without any branching instructions?  That would be substantially trickier, and would probably require several instructions.  Unless you want to simply convert the operands to long values (`i2l`) and then do a `lcmp`.  Anyway, my answer above will give you a 0 or nonzero answer to your original question.  If that suits your needs, could you accept the answer?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any built in instructions for getting a boolean. When you take the value of a comparison in Java, the compiler will generate an if statement and assign 0 on one branch and 1 on the other.

```
boolean b = (2 == 2)
```

Is equivalent to

```
boolean b;
if (2 == 2) { b = true; } else {b = false;}
```